# Reading XML from an URL python, Filtering XML elements by child element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to check if an element has an other element inside.
the url element sometime contain loc tag alone and sometimes loc and image tag, i want to get the value of the loc tag when there is an image tag as well, i tried something like this.

```
url = "https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/media/sitemap_en.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
links = []
for elm in root.findall(".//{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url"):
    if elm.find('.//{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}image) is not None:
        link = elm.find('./{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc').text
        links.append(link)
        return links
```

but still it returns loc tag of all url parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print `<loc>` tags and `<image>` urls tags:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


url = "https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/media/sitemap_en.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
links = []
for elm in root.findall(".//{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}url"):
    loc = elm.find(".//{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}loc")
    img = elm.find(".//{http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1}image")
    if not loc is None and not img is None:
        img_loc = img.find(
            ".//{http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1}loc"
        )
        print(loc.text)
        print(img_loc.text)
        print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/magpul-moe-grip-sl-s-stock-midnight-marshland-furniture-set
http://d2df4e9l5rljaz.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/61578878e6753b4ec73e244e03a0515d/a/p/aprh101361c-magpul-moe-grip-sl-s-stock-midnight-marshland-furniture-set-3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/battle-rope-2pt0-357-38-cal-9mm-pistol
http://d2df4e9l5rljaz.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/61578878e6753b4ec73e244e03a0515d/a/p/aprh101753-battle-rope-2pt0.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/battle-2pt0-rope-22-223-cal-pistol-rifle
http://d2df4e9l5rljaz.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/61578878e6753b4ec73e244e03a0515d/a/p/aprh101754-battle-rope-2pt0.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```